# Failed to flash file gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

All the times I try to install Google Play Services in my emulator I am getting the message:

```
Failed to flash file gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip Genymotion
```

Step-by-step:

- I downloaded the gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip
- I drag and drop it to emulator
- Emulator identify the flashable file and ask me if I wanna flash it...
- After some loading time comes the message of fail.

Important information:

- My emulator is Genymotion 2.3.1 - Android 4.4.4 Kitkat.
- I already installed the Genymotion-ARM-Translation and it flashed ok.
- I am using a Mac 10.10.1, the option Open Save Files of Safari is not checked.

Comment: have completely the same issue…

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried
    `adb push gapps-kk-20140606-signed.zip  /sdcard/`